# Defining function for prime number in a range

Tags: python, function

Could be a very basic question, i am try to define a function that will print out:

Number
"Prime" or "Not Prime"

Below is my code which presented this error : TypeError: isprime() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

```
def isitprime(n):
        for i in range(2,n+1):
             for y in range (2,i):
                 if i % y == 0:
                   isPrime = False
             if isPrime:
                  print(i)
                  print('Prime')
             else:
                  print(i)
                  print('Not Prime')
```

Comment: There is no `isprime` in the code you included in your question.

Comment: Checking prime numbers should have only one for loop i.e. `for i in range(2, n)` (not n+1) since n will always be a divisor of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass an argument when you called the function

```
isitprime(5)
```

has the argument 5

Answer (score 0):

## Try This:

```
def isitprime(n):
prime = True
for i in range(int(n+1/2)):
    if(i==0 or i==1):
        continue
    elif(n % i==0):
        prime = False
if prime is True:
    print(str(n) + " is prime")
else:
    print(str(n) + " is not prime")
isitprime(7)
```

Comment: Suppose if  i want it show from range 2-5
For example:

2 is prime number
3 is prime number
4 is not prime number
5 is prime number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get confused by declaring a variable. You can simply do as below: The logic behind this is if that number is divisible by any number except 1 and that number then break the loop else it will continue. When that loop ends if that number is not divisible any number then it is prime.

```
def isitPrime(n):
   for num in range(2,n+1):
       for i in range(2, num):
          if (num % i) == 0:
             print(num)
             print("not prime")
             break
       else:
          print(num)
          print("prime")


n = int(input())
isitPrime(n)
```

And if you take time complexity in to consideration then you can iterate the second loop in range `(2 to n//2)` or `(2, int(math.sqrt(num)))`